# Disabling SSH passwords for all users except one

Tags: ssh, passwords, authentication

It's easy enough to disable password authentication for SSH as a whole, but is there a way of allowing one user on the system the ability of logging in with a password?

The reason for this is we have several servers at rackspace and we'd like to allow rackspace access to the servers without having to set it up on all of the machines (there are lots!)

If it's simply not possible without editing the source of sshd or something that'd be good to know :)

Comment: This includes all future users, so no per-user rules please unless they can be applied to future users.. perhaps that's the way to do it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the `sshd` configuration, you can apply different settings for *User*, *Group*, *Host*, *LocalAddress*, *LocalPort*, and *Address* using the `Match` directive.

For what you need put this is the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
Match User <USERNAME>
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below commands in to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

1. `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`
2. `PasswordAuthentication no`
3. `UsePAM no`
4. `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Then `reload` SSH service :

> sepahrad@pc:~$ /etc/init.d/ssh reload

Comment: What about my one user that needs to use a password?

Comment: Sorry i forgot it! You can use Match User